# JDBC Caching using result_cache hint

Tags: java, oracle, caching, jdbc, oracle11g

I want to do JDBC Caching, I am using Oracle 11 as database. Using `result_cache` hint can help me here. But I have found it is not working with big resultset (around few thousand records) even though I have set `result_cache_max_size` tor 100mb and `result_cache_max_result` to 60%.

Please help me here ??

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need 11.2 (both server and driver) in order to use the result cache with the thin driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make sure that it actually not the result cache by looking at the execution plan with trace (you should see that it accessing the Result cache and 0 consistent gets) you can find more info here http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=503
2. What is the size of the result set? you can see it by CTS or in the "bytes sent via SQL*Net to client" execution plan property
3. make sure you don't have any one of limitations according to the document ion:

It is not defined in a module that has invoker's rights or in an anonymous block.

It is not a pipelined table function.

It has no OUT or IN OUT parameters.

has one of the following types, BLOB, CLOB, NCLOB, REF CURSOR, Collection,